# CreateRemoteThread MessageBoxA causes remote process to crash

Tags: c++, winapi, virtual-memory, dll-injection

I made a simple program that calculates the RVA of the function `MessaegBoxA` in `user32.dll` and then adds that offset to the base loading address of the dll in the remote process's memory to get the address of the function `MessageBoxA`. I made a *dummy program* that outputs the address of the function in its memory using `GetProcAddress` and then implement my own function in my program to display the address it calculated for the same function in the remote process. They always match so I'm certain my function for finding the address of `MessageBoxA` in remote process's is not the problem.

I made a `struct` that contains all the necessary information and parameters needed for `ThreadProc` to execute `MessageBoxA` in the remote process once I load it using `WriteProcessMemory`.

```
typedef struct
{
    typedef int (WINAPI* _MessageBoxA)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
    _MessageBoxA MessageBoxA;
    //These are the four parameters passed to MessageBoxA
    HWND hwnd;
    LPCSTR msg;
    LPCSTR caption;
    UINT mb;
}MB_DATA, *PMB_DATA;
```

When I try this on my own *dummy program*, the message box shows up but with weird text contrary to the strings I specified in the `msg` and `caption` members of `MB_DATA`. It says the following for the caption `asic_string::erase` and for the message it says `u)`. And when I try to do this in any other process than my *dummy process* it crashes the remote process. I made a function to iterate through the modules that have been loaded in the process with `tlhelp32` functions to make sure `user32.dll` is present and it is and my function for finding the address of the function in the process doesn't return `NULL` like it would if the dll were not present.

Here all relevant functions and my `main` function:

**dependencies.hpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    typedef int (WINAPI* _MessageBoxA)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);
    _MessageBoxA MessageBoxA;
    HWND hwnd;
    LPCSTR msg;
    LPCSTR caption;
    UINT mb;
}MB_DATA, *PMB_DATA;

//Map the dll into memory
void* GetFileImage(char path[])
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, NULL);
    if(hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){printf("Error getting file handle: %d", (int)GetLastError());return NULL;}

    HANDLE file_map = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY|SEC_IMAGE, 0, 0, "KernelMap");
    if(file_map == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){printf("Error mapping file: %d", (int)GetLastError());return NULL;}

    LPVOID file_image = MapViewOfFile(file_map, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);
    if(file_image == 0){printf("Error getting mapped view: %d", (int)GetLastError());return NULL;}

    return file_image;
}

//Get to the function export directory and find the offset for the specified function from the 
//address in memory the dll was loaded at
DWORD_PTR RVAddress(char* image, const char* proc_name)
{
    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDos_hdr = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)image;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNt_hdr = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(image+pDos_hdr->e_lfanew);
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER opt_hdr = pNt_hdr->OptionalHeader;
    IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY exp_entry = opt_hdr.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT];
    PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY pExp_dir = (PIMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY)(image+exp_entry.VirtualAddress);

    DWORD* func_table = (DWORD*)(image+pExp_dir->AddressOfFunctions);
    WORD* ord_table = (WORD*)(image+pExp_dir->AddressOfNameOrdinals);
    DWORD* name_table = (DWORD*)(image+pExp_dir->AddressOfNames);

    for(u_int i=0;i<pExp_dir->NumberOfNames;i++)
    {
        char* name = (char*)(image+name_table[i]);
        if(strcmp(proc_name, name) == 0)
        {
            return (DWORD_PTR)func_table[ord_table[i]];
        }
    }

    return (DWORD_PTR)0;
}

//Add the RVA returned from RVAddress to the address of the dll to find the function in the
//process memory
LPVOID GetProcAddressEx(DWORD dwPid, char* mod_path, char* function_name, char* mod_name)
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    MODULEENTRY32 me32;
    me32.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE|TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, dwPid);
    if(hSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){printf("Snapshot failed");return 0;}

    if(!(Module32First(hSnapshot, &me32)))
    {
        printf("Mod32First failed");
        return 0;
    }

    BOOL found = FALSE;

    while(Module32Next(hSnapshot, &me32))
    {
        if(stricmp(me32.szModule, mod_name) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle(hSnapshot);
            found = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(found == FALSE){return 0;}

    DWORD_PTR RVA = (DWORD_PTR)RVAddress((char*)GetFileImage(mod_path), function_name);

    LPVOID func_addr = me32.modBaseAddr+RVA;
    return func_addr;
}
```

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include "dependencies.hpp"
#define FUNC_SIZE 1024

typedef int (WINAPI* _MessageBoxA)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT);

int main()
{
    MB_DATA mb_data;
    mb_data.hwnd = NULL;
    mb_data.msg = "Hey";
    mb_data.caption = "Yo";
    mb_data.mb = MB_OK;

    SIZE_T nBytes = 0;

    char proc_path[MAX_PATH];
    char kernel_path[MAX_PATH];
    char user32_path[MAX_PATH];

    //get full path to the current process and store it in proc_path
    GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle(NULL), proc_path, MAX_PATH);
    //get full path to kernel32.dll and store it in kernel_path
    GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), kernel_path, MAX_PATH);
    //get full path to user3.dll and store it in user32_path
    GetModuleFileName(GetModuleHandle("user32.dll"), user32_path, MAX_PATH);

    //show all processes running and their PID's
    system("tasklist");

    DWORD dwPid = 0;
    printf("PID: ");
    scanf("%lu", &dwPid);
    //if dwPid is 0 assign it the pid of the current process
    if(dwPid == 0)
    {
        dwPid = GetCurrentProcessId();
    }

    //Get a handle to the process with all access rights
    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwPid);
    //make sure the handle is valid
    if(hProc == NULL){printf("Error obtaining handle to process: %lu", GetLastError());return 1;}

    //Get the address of the function in the remote process
    LPVOID _MessageBoxA1 = GetProcAddressEx(dwPid, user32_path, (char*)"MessageBoxA", (char*)"user32.dll");
    //assign the pointer to the address to the member MessageBoxA of the MB_DATA structure
    mb_data.MessageBoxA = (_MessageBoxA)_MessageBoxA1;

    //allocate 2mb for our the ThreadProc callback function and the MB_DATA structure
    LPVOID lpBase = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, NULL, 2048, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    //did the allocation work
    if(lpBase == NULL){printf("Error allocating space: %lu", GetLastError());return 1;}

    //so I can check what was written with CheatEngine
    cout << "Base address of memory allocated in remote process: " << lpBase << endl;

    //Write the function into memory
    if(WriteProcessMemory(hProc, lpBase, (LPVOID)ThreadProc, FUNC_SIZE, &nBytes) == 0)
    {
        printf("Error writing function to process");
        return 1;
    }

    //the address the space left after having written ThreadProc into memory 
    LPVOID lpBuffer = lpBase+FUNC_SIZE;

    //Write the MB_DATA structure into the memory of the remote process
    if(WriteProcessMemory(hProc, lpBuffer, &mb_data, sizeof(MB_DATA), &nBytes) == 0)
    {
        printf("Error writing buffer to process");
    }

    //Run the ThreadProc function passing the MB_DATA structure to it as its lpParam parameter
    if(CreateRemoteThread(hProc, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lpBase, lpBuffer, 0, NULL) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error creating remote thread: %lu", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    //print a list of all the dll's being used by the process
    EnumerateModules(dwPid);

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: The code as posted isn't complete - you don't show what `ThreadProc` is.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have changed it significantly and found the solution. So it is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mb_data.msg and mb_data.caption point to what in the another process ?? this is already enough for crash error. what is in ThreadProc not visible, but i not sure that it have no relocs. really ThreadProc must be member function of MB_DATA and access only it members. from you post obviously that you not debug remote process at injection time. also obviously that task is over your current level

Comment: I may come off as an insufferable little nooblet but why must `ThreadProc` be a member of `MB_DATA`? And thank you for pointing out the problem with msg and caption. I forgot character arrays automatically decay to pointers.

Comment: "why must ThreadProc be a member of MB_DATA" - it not must be, but it must not containing relocs. as solution - be member function and access only data members of MB_DATA. from another point it in all case member or MB_DATA by fact. void ThreadProc(MB_DATA*); - think it current signature. GetFileImage - you even not try release resources, and at all why not use LoadLibraryEx(DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES) and GetprocAddress in general case

Comment: what do you mean by "relocs"? Relocations?

Comment: How should I go about specifying the `LPCSTR lpText` and `LPCSTR lpCaption` parameters for `MessageBoxA` in the remote process?

Comment: @ProgrammingLad - you need allocate memory and copy string data to remote process, and set mb_data.msg ,mb_data.caption point to this remote addresses. best of all - allocate only 1 block of memory in remote process, and in this block - code, MB_DATA and string data

Comment: @RbMm: What's the advantage of allocating memory and copying the data into the remote process over mapping the same file mapping object?

Comment: @IInspectable - what you mean under "mapping the same file mapping object" - which file/module map ? all what need here (if we only MessageBox want :) ) copy litle code, string data and some pointers in MB_DATA struct

Comment: A file mapping object is a named kernel object. You can map the same file mapping object into multiple processes. There is no need to manually allocate memory or copy structures across. Just map the same file mapping object into the remote process and be done.

Comment: @IInspectable - no, i know what is section(file mapping) object. i ask about another - what image you want map ?

Comment: @IInspectable - you mean all exe mup in remote process as data section, than calc RVA -> file offset -> remote pointer and use ? also variant. exist different choice

Comment: @RbMm so you're saying I need to make a separate allocation and then a separate write operation to insert the strings in the remote process? GENIUS, way better than what I was thinking. I was trying to make them in my own process and pass the PID and pointer to the strings to the other process in the MB_DATA along with `OpenProcess` and `ReadProcessMemory` and then have it copy the strings from my process. You saved me a huge headache. :)

Comment: @RbMm Awesome! It displayed the proper text instead of the garbage it was displaying! And it even worked on the process I've been trying to get it to work on besides my _dummy program_. THANKS!

Comment: @ProgrammingLad: You are trying way too hard. Simply place your `MB_DATA` in a file mapping object, and open that file mapping object in the remote process. No need to allocate or copy memory. Just give the mapping a unique name (like a GUID), and you're done. In case it matters, file mapping objects are securable.

Comment: @IInspectable I know how to map a file into memory but how would I map my `MB_DATA` structure into memory? Would I even use `CreateFileMapping`?

Comment: `CreateFileMapping` in your server process (pass `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` for the file handle), and `OpenFileMapping` in the client process. Pass the same name to either call, and the backing memory is replicated. No need to fumble around with `VirtualAllocEx` or `WriteProcessMemory`. The memory has the same contents in either process. Simply populate it in your controlling process, and read it in the remote process.

Comment: @IInspectable: that's an interesting approach, but it presumes that you've already successfully injected code into the remote process, which doesn't seem to be the case here.  (And the name of the mapping would be a string, so at a minimum you'd have to copy that over somehow.)

Comment: ... although perhaps you could duplicate the handle, since that's a single integer which could be passed as the argument to the new thread.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm going to have to write the name of the file mapping object and a pointer to the `OpenFileMapping` function anyways to be able to access it once it's mapped into memory anyways which means I would have to make a separate data structure. Which avoids more calls to `WriteProcessMemory` but seems like more work and headache. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @IInspectable of course we can create memory section(file mapping on your language), map it in both local and remote process, copy all needed data to it, unmap from local and create remote thread in remote. but about named section you wrong - this is senseless. we have no code in remote process, which can open section by name. this is also working way, i simply say what is wrong in initial solution and offered the closest solution to the existing. in general this 2 ways is suitable only if need small chunk of code execute remote, which can be coverete by single function.

Comment: in another case we need or use DLL on disk(by call LoadLibrary in remote) or inject shellcode+DLL data in memory and shellcode load DLL from memory

Comment: @ProgrammingLad: The file mapping object name can be a constant, so you don't have to transfer it. `CreateRemoteThread` takes a pointer, so you can pass the address to `OpenFileMapping`.

Comment: @IInspectable - for what name ?? we can map section from self(local) process to the remote

Comment: if use section(file mapping) - not need open and map it in remote process. we need create and map it only from local process

Comment: @RbMm I've tried `LoadLibraryA` but the particular application I'm working on has a unique way of sandboxing different instances of itself specifically to avoid dll injection. It doesn't even crash, it just shuts itself down as soon as I try to execute any code inside it from an outside process. But I'll look into the second method you mentioned.